# JAX-WS Web Service is not updating when source code is modified and Web Service is regenerated

Tags: java, web-services

I created two services `public String add(int x, int y)` and `public String sub(int x, int y)`. Now, the definition of these services are as follows:

```
package com.webservice.calc;

import javax.jws.WebService;;

@WebService
public class Calculator {

    String s;
    public String add(int x, int y)
    {
        s = "Sum of "+x+" and "+y+" is : "+(x+y);
        return s;
    }

    public String sub(int x, int y)
    {
        s = "Sum of "+x+" and "+y+" is : "+(x-y);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Instead of writing **Difference**, I wrote **Sum** in the `sub` service as well.

Then I used, **wsgen** tool to generate the wsdl file and using Endpoint publisher, I published it.

Then, I created another project (Web Service Consumer) and using **wsimport**, imported the web service.

The code went fine. But, now I wanted to change the **Sum** to **Difference**.

I changed the code in the original code, then used **wsgen**, then republished (here there was an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Server Runtime Error: Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.publish(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Unknown Source)
    at com.webservice.calc.endpoint.CalcEndpointPublisher.main(CalcEndpointPublisher.java:12)
Caused by: Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

)
  it and again imported it. But no changes. What is the issue here?

Comment: Looks like you want to start your service on address that is already taken by another service. Maybe you didn't kill older one?

Comment: How to kill the older one? I am totally new to it. So unaware

Comment: I think that you can just kill process. If you running it from cmd use `ctrl + c` if from eclipse just go to terminal and hit red square button.

Comment: @mlethys thanks. Got the red button.